# How do I diagnose differences in GNU ld linker behaviour over time?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, ld, memory-alignment

I have a small x86-64 assembly program which I compiled and linked in 2018. I am now trying to reproduce the build, but at the point of linking I get different results in the final binaries.

Both files were assembled and linked using the following command:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 prng.asm; ld -s -o prng prng.o
```

The original ELF that I created in 2018 is named `prng`. The version I created today is named `prng2`. I have verified that the intermediate object files `prng.o` are identical so I'm ruling out the source code or nasm as the cause of the differences I'm seeing. Below I've shown the output from `objdump` on each of the ELFs, old and new:

Original:

```
$ objdump -x prng

prng:     file format elf64-x86-64
prng
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000102:
EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x00000000004000b0

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000400000 paddr 0x0000000000400000 align 2**21
         filesz 0x0000000000000150 memsz 0x0000000000000150 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000150 vaddr 0x0000000000600150 paddr 0x0000000000600150 align 2**21
         filesz 0x0000000000000008 memsz 0x0000000000000008 flags rw-

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000000a0  00000000004000b0  00000000004000b0  000000b0  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000008  0000000000600150  0000000000600150  00000150  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

Latest:

```
$ objdump -x prng2

prng2:     file format elf64-x86-64
prng2
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000102:
EXEC_P, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000401000

Program Header:
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000400000 paddr 0x0000000000400000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000000e8 memsz 0x00000000000000e8 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000001000 vaddr 0x0000000000401000 paddr 0x0000000000401000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000000a0 memsz 0x00000000000000a0 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000002000 vaddr 0x0000000000402000 paddr 0x0000000000402000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000000000000008 memsz 0x0000000000000008 flags rw-

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000000a0  0000000000401000  0000000000401000  00001000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000008  0000000000402000  0000000000402000  00002000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

I can see that the difference seems to be down to the different alignments. However, I cannot determine what has caused different alignments to be used.

- I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 today, whereas in 2018 I was using Ubuntu 16.04.
- I'm using an AMD Ryzen 3700X CPU today, whereas in 2018 I was using an Intel Core i7-860.

I believe the version of `ld` will have changed between the two versions of Ubuntu. Is it likely that ld's behaviour on alignment changed during that time, e.g. with a different default linker script?

Or could the CPU be influencing choice of alignment values?

And why are there three sections of program header now, whereas there were only two before?

Comment: It was a change for security reasons because of page granularity of protection flags.

Comment: @Jester - thanks, can you point to an account of exactly what changed (and hopefully a hint as to how to reverse the effect)?

Comment: You could build an old version of GNU binutils from source, or get `ld` from a binary package.  Or maybe write your own linker script that puts `.rodata` in the same program segment as `.text`, instead of a separate read-without-exec page.  (That's the change Jester ware talking about.)

Comment: the processor should not have any affect, but tools are under constant development and no reason to expect the same code to have the same output from one tool to another be it different toolchains or different versions of the same.  if you go back to the older tools on the new computer, do you get the same results?  if you are just using the C library that is part of the distro, then the linker script or bootstrap may very well have changed changing the alignment, etc

Comment: This kind of question would benefit from a paragraph on why this matters, so we can address the specific concerns which lead to this question.

Comment: Not to mention the libraries being under constant development as well, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern `ld` puts the `.rodata` section in a separate read-without-exec page.  That requires putting it in a separate ELF *segment* (program header entry, read by the loader).  Terminology: ELF *sections* are things listed in the Sections list, after the Program Header listing.

Older `ld` put `.rodata` into the same segment as `.text`, read-only with exec. This did change within the last couple years, like maybe 2018?  (I've been using Arch GNU/Linux since about 2017, a rolling-release distro that mostly uses upstream sources unmodified, and it changed sometime around then IIRC.)

Older `ld` also had the ELF headers, and initializers for `.data`, in the same disk page as the start of `.text`.  (For small files where .data and .text totalled less than 4k).  This disk page was mapped 2 different ways: Read + Exec for the text segment, at the virtual address used for code and read-only data, and Read + Write for the data segment, used for `.data`.

Note the entry point address of `0x00000000004000b0` (some small offset from the start of a page, after the ELF headers + data) vs. `0x0000000000401000` page aligned in the new executable.  **Aligning data on disk allows mapping into virtual memory without overlap of anything into the executable segment that doesn't need to be executable.**  The natural consequence of that is page-aligned memory addresses, but that's a side-effect, not the goal.

Your executable file doesn't have a `.rodata` section (and neither does your input), but the ELF headers themselves are still mapped in a segment with the LOAD attribute (map into memory).

BTW, prefer using `readelf`, not `objdump` for examining ELF headers.

---

**This change helps protect against ROP and Spectre attacks by not making constant data available as "gadgets" to jump to**.  (Now that most programs make code-injection impossible by ensuring W^X, more sophisticated attacks have to look for existing executable byte sequences.  So the next step in hardening is making as few pages as possible executable that don't need to be.)

It has nothing to do with the CPU you're running on, or that you built on.  As @old_timer points out, you shouldn't expect identical binaries from different versions of the toolchain.  Changes to defaults like this are certainly possible for this or other reasons, or even for a tool to embed a tool version signature into the metadata somewhere.  (Compilers like GCC do that, probably NASM and `ld` don't.)

---

You could build an old version of GNU binutils from source, or get an old ld from a binary package.

Or maybe write your own linker script that puts `.rodata` in the same program segment as `.text`.  (I think `ld` works by having a default linker script; if you can find the default linker script in older ld sources, you might be able to use it with the current ld you have installed.)

Comment: There's no `.rodata` input section here.  The read-only no-execute program segment exists solely for the ELF headers.    The original executable put the ELF headers, the `.text` segment and the `.data` segment into the same "page" in the file.  It then mapped this same page of the file into two different program segments, so that the pages at 0x400000 and 0x600000 in memory were mapped to the same first page of the file.  It's not constant data that could be potentially exploited as gadgets, but the ELF headers and the writable `.data` segment.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks, yeah I did comment on the lack of an actual `.rodata` section and wasn't sure why there was a read-only `LOAD` segment.  However, even in older ld's output, the writeable mapping is CoW "private", so it was still a matter of exposing static file contents as executable, not violating W^X.  But yes, those contents include ELF headers and `.data` initializers, as well as `.rodata`.